# Group by portion not appears in codeigniter datatable query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join, datatable

I am trying to use group by in datatable query as per below:

but group by portion is not appears in query which I printed.

datatable query:

```
$this->datatables->select('banks_users.id,users.created_at,username');
$this->datatables->from('banks_users');
$this->datatables->join('users', 'banks_users.users_id = users.id', 'LEFT OUTER');
$this->datatables->join('banks', 'banks.id = banks_users.banks_id', 'LEFT OUTER');
$this->datatables->join('branches_agents', 'branches_agents.users_id = users.id');
$this->datatables->join('branches', 'branches.id = branches_agents.branches_id');
$this->datatables->join('banks_countries', 'banks_countries.banks_id = banks_users.banks_id', 'LEFT OUTER');
$this->datatables->join('countries', 'countries.id = banks_countries.countries_id', 'LEFT OUTER');
$this->datatables->where('users.user_type', 'bank');
$this->datatables->group_by('banks_users.id');
$data = json_decode($this->datatables->generate());
```

But it dont consider `group by` and generates query like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS numrows
FROM banks_users
LEFT OUTER JOIN users ON banks_users.users_id = users.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN banks ON banks.id = banks_users.banks_id
JOIN branches_agents ON branches_agents.users_id = users.id
JOIN branches ON branches.id = branches_agents.branches_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN banks_countries ON banks_countries.banks_id = banks_users.banks_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN countries ON countries.id = banks_countries.countries_id
WHERE users.user_type = 'bank'
```

So, anyone please help...

Comment: The output of query generated doesn't match with your build query. See in your query you are using `select` statement but in output it is showing `count(*)`. Are you using two different queries for **count** and **select**. if yes than you need to add `group_by` statement in your count query too.

Comment: don't worry for that... Please only reply your output if you know. and its only one query I used `echo $this->db->last_query();` to print this output

Comment: Please check your **Datatables library version**. checkout this [version] (https://github.com/IgnitedDatatables/Ignited-Datatables/blob/master/application/libraries/Datatables.php) which support `group_by`. in previous version I think it's not available and I have used this and it will generate proper query with group by. for e.g. `SELECT COUNT(*) AS numrows FROM users_details ud JOIN users u ON u.id = ud.user_id JOIN users_groups ug ON ug.user_id = ud.user_id WHERE ug.group_id = 2 AND ud.status != 2 GROUP BY ud.id`

Comment: Better  ```->groupBy('column');```